# Function in matrix form

Tags: matlab

I have a question wrt to declaring function as a matrix in MATLAB. I want to declare the following variable as a matrix form in function

```
a = [ 1,0.7,3,1,5,4];
```

This variable is stored as column vector as shown below and the code continues  by using this variable

```
variable(:,1) = a;
```

I want to declare this as a function which accepts input parameters which are "1,0.7,3,1,5,4" as assigned for 'a'

Note: The input parameters can be 'n' but not only five

Can you please let me know, how can i declare a function with a matrix using these input parameters

For example:

```
function quantity= data(a)
    data= prod(1:a);
end
```

If i want to call this function, i use
`data(4)` and i get my result

now can i call this function using a matrix for below example?

```
function quantity= data(a)
    variable(:,1) = a;
end
```

If i use `data(1,0.7,3,1,5,4)` , it throws error.

Please let me know incase it is still not clear

Comment: Yes ....i have other row vector variables too and in the end i will convert them to column form and perform calculations

Comment: `function output=my_fun(a),
variable(:,1) = a;  
%assign output;  
output=variable(:,1) *2;  
end`  
  
    Is this what you want?

Comment: please refer the added information

Comment: Have you tried to call it like this `data([1,0.7,3,1,5,4])` with the brackets

Comment: Yes..... Thanks alot..... its because of square brackets inside too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: data([1,0.7,3,1,5,4])

```
function quantity= data(a)
    quantity(:,1) = a;
end
```

Output:

ans =

```
1.0000
0.7000
3.0000
1.0000
5.0000
4.0000
```